# Is Agora Video Call Service Usable in United Arab Emirates

Tags: agora

I wanna build a chat application which will consist of video and voice call so I'm planning to integrate agora, is agora supported in UAE

I did try referring the documentation and all couldn't find any details, in any other search engine too